# How do I unhide Debug -> Attach to Process in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, debugging

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 Professional at work.  Recently, I got a new workstation.  Someone else installed all the software for me.

For some reason, I do not see the option "Attach to Process" on the debug menu.  I looked in the options, but I don't see an option that seems like it should hide it.

How do I make the option "Attach to Process" appear on the debug menu?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to Tools->Customize.  In the Commands tab, look in the Categories list.  Find the Debug entry.  In the right side, select the "Attach to Process..." entry.  Drag it back up to your Debug pull down menu.

Answer (score 3):

It could be a privilege issue.  Attaching a debugger to a process requires that the user have [Debug Privilege](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd450387.aspx) (and that the process doesn't deny the same).

You should still be able to debug processes that you create without this privilege, you just can't attach to processes.

Answer (score 2):

You could try resetting the options to defaults:

Tools > Import and export settings ... > Reset all settings.

If you export your current settings first (from the same menu item) then you can recover them afterwards if it doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio 2008 has a number of environment types.  The environment types hide some options that it believes you might not need.  If the person that installed the software chose "Web Developer" instead of "General Development Settings" then the "Attach to Process" option would be hidden from you.  Using the "Reset All Settings" option will not unhide the option for you.  I don't believe there's an way to change your environment type in the user interface.  I've always reinstalled Visual Studio to fix this issue.